# ImageSharp RecolorBrush not available anymore?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, imagesharp

I'm using ImageSharp version 2.1.3 in a .NET 6 project. Now the API which I can use seems to be different from what is shown in the official [documentation](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api). For instance the docs are pointing to a namespace `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing` which is not part of the NuGet package I received.

One thing I cannot find is the `RecolorBrush` documented [here](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp.Drawing/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing.Processing.RecolorBrush.html). It allows me to replace a color with another one like this:

```cs
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing.Processing;

using (var image = Image.Load('file.png'))
{
    var brush = new RecolorBrush(Color.White, Color.Transparent, 0.2F);
    image.Mutate(ctx => ctx.Fill(brush));
    image.Save('transparent.png');
}
```

Several things are now not working:

1. `RecolorBrush` is not a thing in my Nuget.
2. `ctx.Fill` seems to be no longer available.

So am I missing a package, is this a breaking change and if yes what is the new way to do it and where can I find some official info on this?

Comment: Did you take note of which assembly the documentation says the type is in?

Comment: @madreflection Yes but this does'nt help me here because all assemblies have to be part of the Nuget and there is no other special package for `SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing.dll` as far as I can tell.

Comment: [SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing)

Comment: If you [search for "ImageSharp" on nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ImageSharp), it's the second result.

Comment: @madreflection Ahhh, it's Beta still. Thats why I didn't find it in the search because you have to hit the checkmark. You should post this as an answer so that I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this. Big shoutout to @madreflection which answer pointed me to the fact that I had to enable Nuget prereleases.